# Can't update data in database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't update data in a record in CodeIgniter . Instead of updating it's adding new record in database table.'hotelres_id' is the primary key of my table.

I have posted the code below:-

Controller code for update:-

```
function edit($id){
    $this->load->model('hotel_reservation','mb');
    $data['message'] = '';
    $data['object'] = $this->mb->find_by_id($id);

    if($data['object']){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roomno', 'Room Number', 'required|is_unique[hotel_reservation.roomno]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkin', 'Check In', 'required|is_unique[hotel_reservation.checkin]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkout', 'Check Out', 'required|is_unique[hotel_reservation.checkout]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            $this->mb->eventreg_id = $_POST['hotelres_id'];
            $this->mb->eventreg_id = $_POST['eventreg_id'];
            $this->mb->eventhotel_id = $_POST['eventhotel_id'];
            $this->mb->roomno = $_POST['roomno'];
            $this->mb->checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
            $this->mb->checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
            $this->mb->comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $this->mb->update();
            $data['message'] = 'Details updated successfully';
            $data['object'] = $this->mb;
        }
        $this->load->view('core/hotel_reservation/edit',$data);
    }
    else{
        $data['message'] = 'No details available!! Fill It!!';  
        $this->load->view('core/hotel_reservation/save',$data);
    }
}
```

View Code :-

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Hotel Reservation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hotel Reservation</h2>
        <?php if(isset($message)&&$message!='') echo "<span class=\"message\">{$message}</span>"; ?>
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('core/hotel_re/edit/'.@$object->hotelres_id); ?>" method="POST" >
            <table class="formtable">

            <tr><td>hotelres_id</td><td><input type="text" name="hotelres_id" id="hotelres_id"  class="textbox" value="<?php echo @$object->hotelres_id; ?>"  readonly></td></tr>
            <tr><td>eventreg_id</td><td><input type="text" name="eventreg_id" class="textbox" value="<?php echo @$object->eventreg_id; ?>"  readonly></td></tr>
            <tr><td>eventhotel_id</td><td><input type="text" name="eventhotel_id" class="textbox" value="<?php echo @$object->eventhotel_id; ?>" readonly></td></tr>


            <tr><td>Room Number</td><td><input type="text" name="roomno"  value="<?php echo @$object->roomno; ?>"  class="textbox" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Check In</td><td><input type="text"  name="checkin" value="<?php echo @$object->checkin; ?>"  class="textbox"></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Check Out</td><td><input type="text" name="checkout" value="<?php echo @$object->checkout; ?>"  class="textbox"></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Comment</td><td><textarea type="text"  name="comment" value="<?php echo @$object->comment; ?>"  class="textarea" ></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="submitbutton"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <span class="validation-errors"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Model code:-

```
<?php
class hotel_reservation extends CI_Model{
    var $hotelres_id;
    var $eventreg_id;
    var $eventhotel_id;
    var $roomno;
    var $checkin;
    var $checkout;
    var $comment;

    static $tablename = 'hotel_reservation';
    static $tableid = 'hotelres_id';
    function find_by_id($id)
    {
        $tableid = self::$tableid;
        $resultset = $this->db->get_where(self::$tablename,array($tableid=>$id),1);
        if($resultset->num_rows()==1)
            return array_shift($resultset->result(get_class($this)));
        return false;
    }

    function find_all()
    {
        $resultset = $this->db->get(self::$tablename);
        return $resultset->result(get_class($this));
    }

    function save()
    {
        $tableid = self::$tableid;
        if(isset($this->$tableid)&&$this->$tableid!=''&&$this->$tableid!=0)
            $this->update();
        else
            $this->insert();
    }

    private function insert()
    {
        $this->db->insert(self::$tablename,$this);
    }

    function update()
    {
        $tableid = self::$tableid;
        $this->db->where($tableid,$this->$tableid);
        $this->db->update(self::$tablename,$this);
    }

    function delete()
    {
        $tableid = self::$tableid;
        $this->db->where($tableid,$this->$tableid);
        $this->db->delete(self::$tablename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sholdn't this `$this->db->where($tableid,$this->$tableid);` be this `$this->db->where($tableid,$this->$hotelres_id);` in the update function

Comment: @kakashihatake2 No its not working....I hv already stored hotelres_id in $tableid. giving me an error undefined symbol $hotelres_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here!!

In your controller, you have done this...

```
        $this->mb->eventreg_id = $_POST['hotelres_id'];
        $this->mb->eventreg_id = $_POST['eventreg_id'];
```

This should be this

```
        $this->mb->hotelres_id = $_POST['hotelres_id'];
        $this->mb->eventreg_id = $_POST['eventreg_id'];
```

And like i Said, the update term should be written like this...

```
$this->db->where($tableid,$this->hotelres_id);
```

Solved?

Comment: Yes it is working :) ...thanks....but only "$this->mb->hotelres_id = $_POST['hotelres_id'];" this correction is required...with this "$this->db->where($tableid,$this->$hotelres_id);" it gives the same error as i told above..undefined..but now working fine thanks again

Comment: I understood, y it was not working... I was doing this `$this->$hotelres_id` rather than `$this->hotelres_id`... Actually, The where function should be like i asked you to write. There was just a mistake of `$` sign. So, please use the update line I edited in my answer, so that your `hotelres_id` is able to find a value in your table that matches the value to `$this->hotelres_id`, sent to your controller. Glad to help :)

Comment: yes it works .actually last time i tried it...But due to this another error ,it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, i think your issue is with this line:

```
$this->db->update(self::$tablename,$this);
```

As you should pass the update function an array with matching keys to your TB columns and values to be updated, with you send the whole object ($this), doesn't also send tableid and tablename?

Answer (score -2):

According to your code (`$this->mb->update();`), it is calling **mb** model. But you have provided code for **hotel_reservation** model. May be some mismatch there.

Comment: Please read this [CodeIgniter Model Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) , before answering this way... :|

Comment: Y was I given -1 on this?

Comment: hope u got your answer :)